# Create web based Data entry application using Aws

Tags: cloud, saas, data-entry

I want to create a web-based data entry application,what should be the road map. can anyone recommend me any courses to create web-based application(AWS)

Answer (score 0):

You need basically a Frontend which has a form to take input, a backend to handle the requests submitted by the client browser as well as a database to store the input.

There are a lot of tools and technologies which you may use to create your app. I would recommend you using MERN stack as it is very popular and uses recent technologies.

You may refer to the following tutorial to create your application.
https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-1/

To abstract most of development tasks you can use other service FireBase to create your app. It will be more easier to create and deploy.